# Shiny / Shinydashboard Disconnected from the server

Tags: shiny-server, shiny, shinydashboard

I am running a Shiny application on Shinyserver (open source) that is supposed to run constantly on a screen. However I get a "Disconnected from the server" after a certain amount of time. I've seen in shinyapps.io there is a function for the "Read Timeout" (Seconds of inactivity before a browser connection to a worker process is considered to be idle and is closed.) Not sure, but maybe this is the source of the problem?

Is there any function for setting this timeout in Shinyserver? I can't find anything in the Documentation http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts

Thanks & Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Check you memory profile first, maybe there is a leak somewhere

Comment: Thanks for your reply - do you mean server or client side? The R process keeps running.

Comment: are you sure you didn't accidentally install a trial of shiny server pro? It has a session timeout that behaves exactly as you mentioned (check 3.4 in the docs).